# Cant pass in parameter to this.style inside settimeout

Tags: javascript

What is the reason that `this.style is undefined`? It only happens when I wrap it in a settimeout function. Usually I feed in the parameters and prop should be defined. This is not the case here. I tried passing in the prop as a parameter to my settimeout functions but that did not do the job either. Why is it undefined and what can I do to fix this?

```
   var clicked = false
    function filter(action, getTag, elem, prop, play, reverse, durationP, durationR) {

     if (typeof durationP && durationR === 'undefined'){
        var durationP = 1000;
            durationR = 1000;
     }; 

        var source = {_id: document.getElementById(elem),
                      _class: document.getElementsByClassName(elem)}

        source[getTag].addEventListener(action, function() {
            if (clicked == false) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this.style[prop] = play
                    clicked = true
                }, durationP)   
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this.style[prop] = reverse
                    clicked = !clicked
                }, durationP)
            }
        })
    }
    filter('click', '_id', 'case', 'filter', 'blur(40px)', 'blur(0px)', 1500, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're within a different context.

Within your timeout function `this` actually refers to the current timeout function, and not the source element which triggered the event.

You can work around this like that:

```
source[getTag].addEventListener(action, function() {
    var self = this;
    if (clicked == false) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.style[prop] = play
            clicked = true
        }, durationP)   
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.style[prop] = reverse
            clicked = !clicked
        }, durationP)
    }
});
```

Or you could use .bind syntax to pass the context to the function:

```
var notClickedFunction = function() {
    this.style[prop] = play
    clicked = true
};

var clickedFunction = function() {
    this.style[prop] = reverse
    clicked = !clicked
};

source[getTag].addEventListener(action, function() {
    if (clicked == false) {
        setTimeout(notClickedFunction.bind(this), durationP)   
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(clickedFunction.bind(this), durationP)
    }
});
```

Comment: I feel so dumb right now. I somehow didnt think about this. Which method is more standard or recognized?